# Not able to get success or failure events to fire on making an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try sending a post request with a JQuery Ajax call, but for the life of me I can't get the success or error event's to fire. The post request sends a file to the backend.

I know for a fact that the file is uploaded successfully as I can see it in the logs of the backend. When I add console log statements to the success/error portions I am not getting any sort logging.

Here is the Html of the form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $("#submitButton").click(function () {
        console.log("sdasd");
        console.log($("#my_file").val());
    });

    $("#reset_button").click(function () {
        $("#my_file").val("");
    });





    $('#submit_button').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            // Your server script to process the upload
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/uploadTest',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: "json",

            // Form data
            data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
            success: function( data ) {
             alert("Test Upload Successful");
           },

           error: function(xhr, status, error) {
               alert("Test Upload Successful");
           },

            // Tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
            // You *must* include these options!
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false


        });
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <!-- COMPONENT START -->
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group input-file">

   <input type="file" name="file" id="my_file">
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- COMPONENT END -->
 <div class="form-group">
  <button id="submit_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
 </div>
 <p>The test must be a .docx file in the specified format </p>

 <p id="file_upload_message"/>
</form>
```

Comment: first look.. you need to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default form redirect .. [**See Here**](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit">
```

Will cause the form to submit to the server and will effectively refresh the page.

Use

```
<button type="button">
```

and the form will not do a submit and your ajax submit will get a chance to go through.